# Toggle an element in HTMX

Tags: htmx

I have the following code

```php-template
<button hx-get="/banner"
        hx-trigger="click"
        hx-target="#banner"
        hx-swap="outerHTML">

<div id="banner"></div>
```

On clicking the button the div is replaced with some text

```php-template
<button hx-get="/banner"
        hx-trigger="click"
        hx-target="#banner"
        hx-swap="outerHTML">

<div id="banner">Hello</div>
```

On clicking the button again, I want the change to be undone. Back to the original state.

Comment: Is it always the same text?  If so, the best way is to use CSS classes to change the `display` attribute from `show` to `hide`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add url query param eg `?show=true` and on the backend side, toggle the `show` param depending on the previous value then pass it back to html.
Example using django:

view:

```
show_text = request.GET('show', 'true') == 'true'
```

template:

```
<button hx-get="/banner?show={% if show_text %}false{% else %}true{% endif %}"
    hx-trigger="click"
    hx-target="#banner"
    hx-swap="outerHTML">

<div id="banner">{% if show_text %}Hello{% endif %}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
<button hx-get="/banner"
        hx-trigger="click"
        hx-target="#banner"
        hx-include="[name=original]"
        hx-swap="outerHTML">

<div id="banner">Hello<input type="hidden" name="original" value=""></div>
```

Your application does not have to remember original value. You just have to write it to the HTML when changing banner.